# Verify with a React Hook if any HTML button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I am trying to use an event listener that will trigger the handle only if any button of any type was clicked, regardless of context for the moment.

```
export const useClickButtonOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      const listener = event => {
        // Do nothing if event is not a button
        if (!(event.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement)) {
          return;
        }

        handler(event);
      };

      document.addEventListener('mousedown', listener);
      document.addEventListener('touchstart', listener, { passive: false });

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', listener);
        document.removeEventListener('touchstart', listener);
      };
    },
   
    [ref, handler]
  );
};
```

Main issue that is hard to achieve this is:

1. The event may point to an element that contains a button, but it is technically not an instanceof the html button. e.g. clicking a svg
2. The hook can applied to different elements of the website, so it should be as dynamic as possible.

Comment: What do you mean with "The event may point to an element that contains a button"? Do you mean an svg inside of a button or a button inside an svg?

Comment: the former, buttons are found in the middle of the path while images are at the bottom as is the standard.

Comment: I think I don't understand, maybe because of my english level. Can you give me an example where that hook don't work?

Comment: Event is triggered by click down, the element i clicked is a button, but event.target says they are an instance of svg or other than the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you have to take a look at the event path, which will contain all the elements where the event was fired. You need to check if this chain contains a button element, if it does, then handle the event.

```
export const useClickButtonOutside = (ref, handler) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const listener = (event) => {
            // Do nothing if path contains a button
            let isButton = false;
            event.path.forEach((element) => {
                if (element.tagName === "BUTTON") {
                    isButton = true;
                    return;
                }
            });
            
            if (!isButton) {
                return;
            }

            handler(event);
        };

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
        document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener, { passive: false });

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
            document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
        };
    }, [ref, handler]);
};
```

Comment: almost works, the tagName does log a BUTTON tag when iterated but isButton will always be undefined for some reason.

Comment: My bad, I tested it wrong. There it is

Comment: Now we are talking, this exactly what i wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain more about the second point?

About the first one, when you click on a button, which has an element inside, you may receive the inside element instead of a button.

For example:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<button>
    <span>Test</span>
</button>
```

That's because you actually had clicked on the span instead of the button, the button receive the event because of the propagation of the event.

To get the element you can do this:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.target.closest('button'));
});
```

```html
<button>
    <span>Test</span>
</button>
```